# push events on hooks gitlab api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, gitlab, cicd

how can I push events on project hooks in gitlab via it's api.

as shown in picture below.
[image]

Comment: What is your goal of doing this? Normally you push your commits to the gitlab repo by writing 'git push' in your command prompt and the push event will trigger the gitlab webhook.

Comment: @kayuapi_my I want to do it with gitlab api.

Comment: Push events are outbound calls(webhook), if you are looking for triggering a pipeline for a repo. Then looking into "Pipeline triggers" tab.